# Wordpress delete mysql rows with string

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, mysql, post-type, customization

So I'm updating the code of an old wordpress plugin(never released), and I want  the database to be "clean" before importing new data otherwise data will just add up and i want it clean before every import, so that duplicates dont happen.

This is the code that i'm using but doesn't seem to work.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->delete( $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_cb_%' ) );
$wpdb->delete( $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'webcam' ) );
```

What's wrong with this picture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows), $wpdb->delete() takes at least two parameters, the table name and the Where-conditions as an array(). LIKE isn't supported for delete imho, so you'll need to use ->query

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_cb_%'" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'webcam'" );
```

I assume the double closing parentheses and missing quotes were just from copy pasting?

Comment: Tried it so many ways except the right one. Even consulted wordpress codex, but i always need more explicit examples. This worked, Thank you.